# Callback function gets called only once

Tags: node.js, apache-zookeeper

I'm writing a ZooKeeper client to monitor a node. The callback function gets called only the first time I change the data of the node. I'm not sure why the function doesn't execute on the second change.

A second query is that my program terminates if I uncomment the last `close()` function. As a good practice, I should use the `close()` function but then it doesn't enter the blocking state to listen to the incoming events. How do I achieve it? I've read the documentation but couldn't find anything useful.

```
var zookeeper = require("node-zookeeper-client");

var client = zookeeper.createClient("192.168.43.172:2181");
var path = process.argv[2];

client.once("connected", function() {
  console.log("Connected to the server.");
  client.create(path, new Buffer("data"), function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Failed to create node: %s due to: %s.", path, error);
    } else {
      console.log("Node: %s is successfully created.", path);
    }
  });

  client.getData(
    path,
    function(event) {
      console.log("Got event: %s.", event);
    },
    function(error, data, stat) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error.stack);
        return;
      }
      console.log("Got data: %s", data.toString("utf8"));
    }
    );
  //client.close();
});

client.connect();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't have an answer to my second query but for the first query, the zookeeper server is designed to send an event only the first time a change takes place and then delete the switch. In order to keep receiving the events, I had to set a watch again while handling the triggered event. Below is my code:

```
var zookeeper = require("node-zookeeper-client");

var client = zookeeper.createClient("192.168.43.172:2181");
var path = process.argv[2];

client.once("connected", function() {
  console.log("Connected to the server.");

  var watch = function(event) {
    console.log("Got event: %s.", event);
    client.getData(path, watch, getDat);
  };

  var getDat = function(error, data, stat) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error.stack);
      return;
    }
    console.log("Got data: %s", data.toString("utf8"));
  };

  client.getData(path, watch, getDat);
  // client.close();
});

client.connect();
```